# No visible @interface error using enumerateChildNodesWithName?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have ran this project in the past without errors and all the sudden, red flags go up when I try to use:

```
-(void)aimRocketLauncher:(CGPoint)location
{
__block CGPoint handleLocation;


[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"handle" usingBlock: ^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {

    SKSpriteNode *handle = (SKSpriteNode *) node;

    handle.name = @"handle";

    if(CGRectContainsPoint(handle.frame, location)) {

        handle.position = location;
        handleLocation = location;
    }
}];

[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"rocketLauncher" usingBlock: ^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {

    SKSpriteNode *rocketLauncher = (SKSpriteNode *) node;

    CGPoint launcherPosition = rocketLauncher.position;

    CGFloat slope = (handleLocation.y - launcherPosition.y) / (handleLocation.x - launcherPosition.x);
    //NSLog(@"%f", slope);

    CGFloat angle = tan(slope);
    angle *= angle;



    SKAction *rotate = [SKAction rotateToAngle:degToRad(angle + 90) duration:0.05];

    //        if (angle < 270 && angle < 180) {
    //            [rocketLauncher removeAllActions];
    //            [rocketLauncher runAction:rotate];
    //
    //        }





}];

}
```

Not just this one, but all over the project. I tried undoing and cleaning the project.

The exact error:

ARC Semantic Issue No visible @interface for 'GameScene' declares the selector 'enumerateChildNodesWithName:usingBlock:'

It really doesn't matter what the rest of the code is because I know this works. When I start to type [self  the autocomplete finds it and when I right click on enumerateChildNodesWithName then Jump to Definition, it's there. This means that the Sprite Kit is imported correctly. I tried closing out the project and restarting the Mac, still nothing happened.

I tried using this code in another class to see what would happen. Same error.

The only difference I see in the 2 different projects that have this similar code is that one was started in Xcode 5 and this one Xcode 6.

I also do not want to use any sks file whatsoever.

.h

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
#import "Settings.h"
#import "TopHud.h"
#import "Hud.h"
#import "Menu.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class Menu;
@class Settings;
@class TopHud;
@class Hud;

@interface GameScene : SKScene
{

}
@end
```

Top of the .m file

```
#import "GameScene.h"
@implementation GameScene
```

I really need to work out this problem because it's killing my entire project that is fairly large. I'm working on it alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the Deployment Target from 8 to 7.1